# PdfSharp XGraphicsPath.addString Custom font

Tags: pdfsharp

хочу в PDF добавить текст с произвольным шрифтом.
если пользуюсь DrawString, то все добавляется, а AddString работает только с установленными шрифтами, как добавить текст с произвольным шрифтом с помощью XGraphicsPath.AddString ?

```
        // Это работает
        gfx.DrawString("Hello!!", wpBlackFont, XBrushes.Black, x, y);
        var FontFamily = new XFontFamily("Arial");
        var path = new XGraphicsPath();
        var rect = new XRect(0, 0, 250, 140);

        // и это работает:
        path.AddString("Hello!", FontFamily , XFontStyle.Regular, 16, rect, XStringFormats.Center);
        gfx.DrawPath(new XPen(XColors.Purple, 1), XBrushes.DarkOrchid, path);

        // а это НЕ работает:
        path.AddString("Hello!", wpBlackFont.FontFamily, XFontStyle.Regular, 16, rect, XStringFormats.Center);
        gfx.DrawPath(new XPen(XColors.Purple, 1), XBrushes.DarkOrchid, path);
```

ошибка: "Not implemented for font 'Segoe WP Black', because it was retrieved with font resolver."